# Laravel 8 Components

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am trying to create a component, and send it some data.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-wrapper">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">
                <i class="fa fa-pie-{{ $icon ?? '' }} fa-fw"></i>
                <span>{{ $title ?? '' }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-version">
                <i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-fw"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            {{ $content ?? '' }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am then calling that component in Blade using

```
<x-com-card icon="globe" title="Test"> </x-com-card>
```

But I am getting the following error

Undefined variable $icon

My component controller looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class ComCard extends Component
{
    private $icon;
    private $title;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @param $icon
     * @param $title
     */
    public function __construct($icon, $title)
    {
        $this->icon = $icon;
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('com.card');
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: try to set your properties as `public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you set your properties as private, and view can not access them.

> When your component is rendered, you may display the contents of your
> component's **public** variables by echoing the variables by name

```php
public $icon;
public $title;
```

More you can find [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#passing-data-to-components), in official documentation

Comment: Hi, thanks! I have tried this, and it results in a -> Undefined constant "globe" - error!

Comment: sorry, i just made mistake, the problem was perhaps with modifiers, and not with semicolon. semicolon you have to use only you want to pass variable. `<x-com-card icon="globe" :title="$someTitleVariable"`. so i edited the answer

Comment: try this
`<x-com-card icon="'globe'" title="'Test'"> </x-com-card>`